# Combine data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these 2 tables:

dbo.clicks

```
| user_id | campaign_id |
|---------|-------------|
| 1       | 100         |
| 2       | 200         |
| 3       | 300         |
```

dbo.reads

```
| user_id | campaign_id |
|---------|-------------|
| 2       | 200         |
| 4       | 400         |
```

And I want to combine the data to get that result:

```
| user_id | campaign_id | read  | clicked |
|---------|-------------|-------|---------|
| 1       | 100         | false | true    |
| 2       | 200         | true  | true    |
| 3       | 300         | false | true    |
| 4       | 400         | true  | false   |
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is your current attempt?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this one:

```
select 
COALESCE(r.user_id, c.user_id) as user_id,
COALESCE(r.campain_id, c.campain_id) as campain_id,
case when r.user_id is null then 'false' else 'true' end as 'read',
case when c.user_id is null then 'false' else 'true' end as 'clicked'
from reads r
full outer join clicks c on r.user_id = c.user_id
order by 1
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using **LEFT JOIN** to combine both data and find the matching data from dbo.clicks and dbo.reads

```
SELECT
c.user_id,
c.campaign_id,
CASE WHEN r.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END AS read,
CASE WHEN c.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END AS clicked
FROM
    dbo.clicks c
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.reads r ON c.user_id = r.user_id AND c.campaign_id = r.campaign_id;
```

Comment: I think you need `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by performing a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between the `clicks` and `reads` tables on the `user_id` and `campaign_id` columns. After that, you can use the `CASE` statement to determine if a user has read or clicked based on the existence of records in the joined tables.

Refer the below SQL Query for reference:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(c.user_id, r.user_id) AS user_id,
    COALESCE(c.campaign_id, r.campaign_id) AS campaign_id,
    CASE WHEN r.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS [read],
    CASE WHEN c.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS clicked
FROM
    clicks c
FULL OUTER JOIN
    reads r ON c.user_id = r.user_id AND c.campaign_id = r.campaign_id
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(c.user_id, r.user_id), COALESCE(c.campaign_id, r.campaign_id);
```

Comment: A similar answer has already been provided earlier ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/77898331/4286884